# Adobe Reader unable to locate PDFs sent to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, pdf, adobe

I can open my PDFs from iBooks, but Adobe Reader cannot find them on the iPhone.

How can I open them in Adobe Reader, which I prefer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're transferring your pdf files through itunes, you need to open your device in iTunes, then select Adobe reader from the apps file sharing section and drag/drop the files you want to open with adobe.
[image: Copy pdf to Adobe Reader through iTunes]